# How does Entity Framework (v4 and up) perform for massive (1 million plus rows) queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am currently exploring of using Entity framework for the windows based (forms) application I'm developing that does data mining  for a dataset of more than 1 million rows (my datasources are from oracle, sql server, sqlite). What the application will do is I parse these information to the users local client, and I utilize linq to objects in mining useful information. The said application shall only read information to the source database as its output is written in an excel file.

Given the significant ease of using the Entity Framework in terms of reducing the development time (this is the first time I will be using an ORM, and coding the necessary dataaccess objects takes about 80% of my time based on the previous projects I've done before), I would like to ask if it's worth it to use EntityFramework to the application I'm working in? How much would be the performance drop (as compared to using DataReaders) when reading tables for over 1 Million rows?

Also, given that I'm new to this technology, I would much appreciate it if you could refer me to useful tutorials and best practices.

Comment: Your question seems more directed towards an ETL tool. Something like SSIS can easily do what you intend to achieve. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: 1 million rows - are you using a 20 year old computer? I mean, today we deal regualrly with 10 billion row tables and this is fast . 1 million rows you just pull into the  client.

Comment: @marc_s The database (oracle actually) are properly indexed. My question is that if I use Entity Framework for my application will the parsing of data from the database will be as fast compared to creating an OracleCommand object and then creating a datareader to that table.

Comment: @CoderPanda I'm aware of the ETL tools, I just wanna ask if there is a performance drop when I use Entity Framework as this will be the first time I will be using an ORM

Comment: Okay. There are many good arguments for and against ORMs. Instead of writing a big answer, I would prefer to point you to something that I read recently. It is fairly detailed.
Against: http://wozniak.ca/what-orms-have-taught-me-just-learn-sql
For: https://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/reply-to-what-orms-have-taught-me-just-learn-sql

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the explanation. My primary concern is really to reduce development time. I guess I could live with the performance drop with ORMs.

Comment: Thanks also @CoderPanda. I've read the blog you shared. Luckily, I will be only using simple select statements (no joins) for my project, so I'll be using EF anyway. :)

Comment: If your workload is read-only, consider using a lite ORM (e.g. Dapper or Massive).  These can often have better performance than EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure ADO.NET will give you practically best performance you could get. But bear in mind that after you fetch data from data source, you would still need to map results to your object model (something that is done by EF automatically) so that you can perform actual data mining.

Mapping could be tough or easy process to do depending on **how complex your data model is**. For example, Entity Framework is good at mapping hierarchical data structures, which is useful when fetching related entities (or even their related entities) along with the actual entity. 
You should also consider how often does your data model changes (and how big those changes are), so you calculate maintainability cost too. Having tons of SQL that you have to change every time you add new column is another point of getting problems. In this case, maintaining EF model with POCO's would be easier and more convenient.

Note that there are **other O/RMs** that can give you kind of best of two worlds (performance of DataReader and easy mapping to POCOs of Entity Framework). Among these are: NPoco (former PetaPoco), Dapper (the one used at StackOverflow), NHibernate (using HQL can be quite fast), OrmLite (has basic LINQ-like queries support) and many others.
Take a look at Dapper's [performance benchmarks results](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#performance) that might give you some picture of what performance can be achieved with popular O/RMs.

Performance of either technology of fetching data is really dependent on what data model you have in the database. 
That's why it's **important** not only to analyze existing benchmarks, but also perform your own based on your particular use cases on your data model. As a starting point, you can grab Dapper's [performance tests code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Tests/PerformanceTests.cs) and tweak it according to your needs (data model, typical queries, etc), so that you get more comprehensive and realistic performance results using different frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

EF is never as fast as using *raw* ADO.NET with an `OracleCommand`. After all, EF is another layer on top of ADO.NET; it's main goal is to provide programmers with **convenience features** of mapping raw columns into fields and rows into objects.

If you need the absolute top-notch performance, then you need to use raw ADO.NET. The downside of this is the fact that you need to start fiddling around with untyped rows and columns.

There ain't no free lunch - either you have top performance but an unpleasant programming API, or you get convenience and productivity - at a performance price.